# Downloading a file with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qtnetwork

I am trying to figure out a way for my Qt browser app can download a word document from our web app. The web app is written in ExtJS, when (in a browser such as Chrome) a user clicks the "Download report" button a javascript event listener detects that click and opens a 0px0px iframe and the file downloads. I'm not sure how to replicate this browser feature in Qt?

When I click on the link I get a network reply of `"Operation canceled" 5`?

What class/method would be best to retrieve these files?

[image]

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: did you check values in http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum? In particular something like JavascriptCanOpenWindows?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have enabled it now but still no effect, the operation aborts when I click the "Download report" link. I think this is a job for NetworkAccessManager but not sure how to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to download a file you need : a *QNetworkAccessManager* in this case *http*.
a *QFile* in this case *file*.
a *QNetworkReply* in this case *reply*
connect the reply with a slot that writes the bytes received through *QNetworkAccessManager* in this case the slot is called *readingReadyBytes()*

so i create the request and connect to my slot:

```
 const QNetworkRequest& request = QNetworkRequest(url);
 reply = http->get(request);
 QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this,
        SLOT( readingReadyBytes() ));
```

then i create my slot:

```
 void yourClass::readingReadyBytes() {
    file->write(reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable()));
 }
```

finally you have to save and close your file. tipically is done when the *QNetworkAccessManager* emit the *finished* signal..
this is what i remember and i think it is all..