# Saving downloaded file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have my slot being called whenever someone clicks the link and I know the file is there because I can retrieve the file name and the amount of bytes the file is just not sure how to s ave it after I call the QFileDialog::getSaveFileName? I know that gives me the name of the file if the user decides to change it but how do I get the location they decide to save it in and then write it to that location.

NB: The file they will download is a word doc if that makes any difference?

```
void MainWindow::unsupportedContent(QNetworkReply *reply) {

    qDebug() << "Left click - download!";
    qDebug() << "Bytes to download: " << reply->bytesAvailable();

    QString str = reply->rawHeader("Content-Disposition");

    QString end = str.mid(21);
    end.chop(1);

    qDebug() << "string: " << end;

    qDebug() << "File name: " << reply->rawHeader("Content-Disposition");
    qDebug() << "File type: " << reply->rawHeader("Content-Type");
    QString defaultFileName = QFileInfo(end).fileName();
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"), defaultFileName);
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;


    QFile *file = new QFile(fileName);
    file->open(fileName);
    file->write(reply->read(reply->bytesAvailable()));
    file->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today i explained it on another post so i will link that post here : [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747548/downloading-a-file-with-qt/13761758#13761758)
i can tell you that you have only to implement  a slot that write into the file you created. and call it when *readyRead()* signal is emitted.